# Create a custom control which has a fixed height in designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, designer

I want to create a custom control (derived from Control class), and when I drag this custom control to a form in designer, I can only change its width. This feature is same as single-line textbox.

Update: My application is Windows Form.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See http://www.windowsdevelop.com/windows-forms-general/how-to-set-that-a-control-resizes-in-width-only-9207.shtml.

You override SetBoundsCore and define a Designer to remove top and bottom resize handles.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace MyControlProject
{
    [Designer(typeof(MyControlDesigner))]
    public class MyControl : Control
    {
        protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
        {
            height = 50;
            base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified);
        }
    }

    internal class MyControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
    {
        MyControlDesigner()
        {
            base.AutoResizeHandles = true;
        }
        public override SelectionRules SelectionRules
        {
            get
            {
                return SelectionRules.LeftSizeable | SelectionRules.RightSizeable | SelectionRules.Moveable;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The link is broken. Am I missing a reference? I have the includes, but it still doesn't find the class `ControlDesigner` for me to inherit from. Which is the minimum version of the .NET Framework this class is available?

Comment: Matheus: You have to manually add System.Design as a reference in the project.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, 
   int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
{
   // Set a fixed height for the control.
   base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, 75, specified);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Worked for me as well. The link from the accepted answer seems to be offline, so I'm glad we have this answer.

Comment: Remember to set `specified` to the dimensions which your override changed. In this example, you forcebly define the height, so `specified` should be `BoundsSpecified.Height`.
Like so: `base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, 75, BoundsSpecified.Height);`

Source: [Documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).

Answer (score 1):

```
    this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 20);
    this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 20);
```

Apparently .NET assumes a minimum and maximum width of 0 to be "any width".

Comment: I usually try to reproduce an issue before I answer, but this has been over a year ago; I don't remember answering this question, so perhaps you should just take a look at the accepted answer instead.