# How to create design time support for a control library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, controls

Good afternoon everyone,

I am working on trying to breath new life into a defunct control library, but don't have a lot of experience with custom controls.

One of the issues I've run into is that the control library uses .design.dll files for the GAC for design time support (so you can add and manipulate controls on winforms, etc), but when I compile my trunk of it, I don't get the .design.dll files, just the control library files.

Can someone explain how I compile the design time dll files as well?  Everything is presumably there, since the design time files were generated before support ended, but I don't see a way to actually build them.

I appreciate the help!

I've gone through all of the build settings in Visual Studio and I've tried using the old design time dll files (I can't because the automatically generated token is different).

Comment: See related, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4388922/380384, as a `ControlDesigner` class needs to be linked to the custom control in order to add design time support.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Comment: Are these controls WPF or WinForms?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/37899azc(v=vs.100)

Comment: If a library is in the GAC then you won't need it next to the compiled binaries.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I am going to look at those links now.  I appreciate the help!

To answer the questions:
1) This is for WinForms, not WPF.
2) The Design Time files aren't in the GAC, I'm trying to figure out how to compile them so that I can get them in the GAC.

Thank you all again!

Comment: Hello, if it is convenient, can you share the specific operation steps or other information. For example, there is no reference to the .design.dll file. Is it possible that the .design.dll cannot be referenced because of a problem with your .net framework version.